# Return a query value in php from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone help me to get the value of this query in php

```
     $query30 = " select FLOOR(sum(votes)/count(customer_id)) from votes where product_bc = 98712512653 and customer_id = 9";

     $result30 = mysqli_query($connection, $query30) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

     while($rank[""] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result30)) {  

     $rank[];

     }
```

What i must put in $rank[""]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for a loop. Your query will always return just one row, since it's aggregating all the selected rows into one average. So just write:

```
$rank_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result30);
```

You should assign an alias in the `SELECT` clause so you'll have a meaningful name in the associative array. Otherwise, you'll have to write:

```
$rank = $rank_row['FLOOR(sum(votes)/count(customer_id))'];
```

to get the value.

Also, SQL has a built-in function to calculate the average, you don't need to use `COUNT` and `SUM` yourself.

```
$query30 = "SELECT FLOOR(AVG(votes)) AS avg_vote FROM votes 
            WHERE product_bc = 98712512653 and customer_id = 9";
$result30 = mysqli_query($connection, $query30) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$rank_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result30);
$rank = $rank_row['avg_vote'];
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)) you saved us